# Wordpress - Create post with plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, post

is it possible to create posts with a wordpress plugin by entering a title, content, category and custom field (important)? Somehow I can't find anything about it in the documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API or on Google.

Thanks, Rik.

Answer (score 21):

The function for doing that is [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post).

I've always found WordPress reference section a bit of a PITA to navigate. So you might want to bookmark this page - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference It has a list of all (most) of the available functions for WordPress.

Comment: It looks like there's only support for custom taxonomies and not for custom fields. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Never mind, found it: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/wp-insert-post-php-function-and-custom-fields

Comment: Since you are new on the site, if you find an answer helpful then it helps to give it an upvote or the check to indicate that it helped solve your problem. Cheers.