# How to publish new post in automatically in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a plugin, through that plugin user can publish new post, without using Wordpress post option. Is there any solution available?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053346/wordpress-create-post-with-plugin

Comment: one more option http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp

Comment: Or there is way to publish a new post via a secret email as well in WP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to publish a post from a Plugin, then you have to call the [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) function, with the appropriate details of the new post that you want to create.